# Mounting shared folder in KVM VM error: mount: unknown filesystem type '9p'

Tags: linux, mount, kvm

I'm using Centos 6.4 in a KVM virtual machine, with CentOS 6.4 as host also.
I configured shared folders following these instructions: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio.
When I try to mount the shared folder in the guest machine I get

> mount: unknown filesystem type '9p'.

The command I used is:

> mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio /shared /mnt/shared

I did modprobe -l | grep 9p, and the result is:

```
kernel/net/9p/9pnet.ko
kernel/net/9p/9pnet_virtio.ko
kernel/net/9p/9pnet_rdma.ko
```

The kernel module for virtio filesystem seems to be loaded.

lsmod | grep 9p result is:

```
9pnet_virtio            7350  0 
9pnet                  38652  1 9pnet_virtio
virtio_ring             8301  6 9pnet_virtio,virtio_balloon,virtio_console,virtio_net,virtio_blk,virtio_pci
virtio                  4977  6 9pnet_virtio,virtio_balloon,virtio_console,virtio_net,virtio_blk,virtio_pci
```

I installed all the packages in connection with qemu-kvm, virtio, 9p ... 
The same error. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen only with KVM or also without? A more generic howto at: https://superuser.com/questions/628169/how-to-share-a-directory-with-the-host-without-networking-in-qemu

Comment: `cat /proc/filesystems` will tell you which filesystems are supported by the current running kernel.

Comment: The CentOS 6 distro does not enable 9pnet_fs, you will have to compile your own kernel or module with dkms.  `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep -i 9p` will show you what is enabled in the kernel.  `CONFIG_9P_FS` is what you are looking for.